# linux command of text file processing working in terminal but not in PHP

Tags: linux, terminal, php, xampp

I am processing by cutting (keeping the original data as well) the first row and first column and saving new file under another filename. I can execute the command in Terminal, but the same code is not working in PHP in Xampp.
The input file looks like as below
codes I am using in the terminal.

```
grep -v 'Pub' filename1 | cut -d ',' -f2- > filename2
perl -pi -e 's/\n/,+1\n/g' filename2
```

The code I'm using in PHP script in Xampp is

```
system("grep -v 'Pub' $dir/filename1 | cut -d ',' -f2- > $dir/filename2");
system("perl -pi -e 's/\n/,+1\n/g' $dir/filename2");
```

filename 1 (delimater = ,)

> Name,nAcid,ALogP,ALogp2,AMR,apol,naAromAtom,nAromBond,nAtom
>
> "mol1",0,-2.0696,4.28324,227.7164,130.7204,0,0,116

filename 2 (output i want)

> 0,-2.0696,4.28324,227.7164,130.7204,0,0,116

Comment: I know nothing about PHP (hence just a comment) but I *suspect* `system()` runs the given command itself, not the command in a shell. `|`, `>` etc. need to be interpreted by a shell. Can you take it from here and investigate?

Comment: ^^^ This. Write a shell script and call that from php.

Comment: Why call system when all that can be done in pure php?

Comment: thanks, @KamilMaciorowski and @DavidPostill but I'm not so aware of PowerShell scripts and also not so much help over PowerShell, If you can make on, it will be a great help.
@Toto, I tried to run without `system()` but it failed as well